# Размер выпадающего окна в хроме

Tags: google-chrome, javascript, chrome-extension

У меня написано расширение для хрома. На страничке есть несколько табиков. Один таб заполнен информацией и отображается нормально. Когда же происходит переключение на следующий, окно сжимается до минимума. При этом размеры всех элементов выставлены в максимум. Если открыть страницу как обычно, через браузер, все ок. Как правильно выставить размер страницы в расширение хрома?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Размер окошка расширения определяется внутренней разметкой. Если разметка пустая, то окошко сожмется до минимума - это правильное поведение. Чтобы этого избежать, надо определить размеры. Это можно сделать по разному, самый простой способ:

```
<body width="100" height="100" />
```